# What is an example of a class decorator which overrides `__getattribute__` or `__getattr__`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, operator-overloading

Suppose that we want to overload the dot-operator, also known as `__getattribute__`

```python
obj.insert()
obj.__getattribute__("insert")()  

height = rectangle.height
height = rectangle.__getattribute__("height")
```

Is there someway to write a class decorator which  overrides `__getattribute__` or `__getattr__`?

How do you override `__getattribute__` or `__getattr__` in the interface, but not the implementation?

```python
import itertools 

@decorate
def MultitudeOfThings:  
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if len(kwargs) > 0:
            raise NotImplementedError()    
       self._args   = args 
       self._kwargs = kwargs  

   def __copy__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if len(kwargs) > 0:
            raise NotImplementedError()    
       left      = self._args.__getitem__(self, arg[0], **kwargs): 
       leftovers = self._args[1:]
       return type(self)(itertools.chain(iter([left]), iter(self[leftovers])))
```

So, we have...

```python
MultitudeOfThings = decorate(MultitudeOfThings)
```

Now, the new `MultitudeOfThings` should have a custom-made method named `__getattribute__` or named `__getattr__`.

However, the line of code `self._args = args` inside of the old `MultitudeOfThings.__init__` should use the old `MultitudeOfThings.__getattribute__` not the new `MultitudeOfThings.__getattribute__`

Below is an example of the overloaded (overridden?) dot operator:

```python
def __getattribute__(self, attrname:str):   
    return type(self)(getattr(arg, attrname) for arg in self._args)
```

Comment: Its unclear what you want to achieve with the override.

Comment: "However, the line of code self._args = args inside of the old MultitudeOfThings.__init__ should use the old MultitudeOfThings.__getattribute__ not the new MultitudeOfThings.__getattribute__" Then it **is not overriden then**. It really isn't clear to me what behavior you even want exactly

Comment: @flakes You wrote that it is unclear what I wanted to achieve with the override. I provided the implementation of the overriden `__getattribute__` method in the original posting/question, but there are one or more mistakes in what I wrote. Ideally, the `args` parameter inside of `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` will be a tuple similar to the tuple returned by the function call `tuple(getattr(arg, attrname) for arg in self._args)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Most of the calls to `__getattribute__` located inside of the implementations of class methods will use the  method named `__getattribute__` inherrited from the `object` class. Most of calls to `__getattribute__` located outside of the implementations of class methods will use the user-defined method named `__getattribute__`.

Comment: So you want to loop through a list of objects and pull out attributes with a particular name from each? Please write an example usage with expected inputs and outputs. The implementation you're going for seems highly overly engineered for the problem at hand. Why not express this as a normal method that takes the attribute as a string parameter? Python can do many things, but many of those things are not pythonic. See [Avoiding the magical wand](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/#avoid-the-magical-wand)

Comment: @flakes The question was how to make sure that attribute access from outside of the class used a different implementation of `__getattribute__` than attribute access inside of class methods such `__init__`. If you have a class named `Rectangle` then `self._getattribute__("width")` inside of `Rectangle.__init__` will do something different than `obj._getattribute__("width")`  where `obj` is an instance of `Rectangle` and `obj` is instantiated outside of any method of the `Rectangle` class.

Comment: What you are describing isn't "overriding". You basically want to intercept calls *only* from "outside the class", which really isn't well defined. in any case, that may be possible, depending on how you define "outside the class". If you could put together some basic requirements of what that means exactly, I think this would be more answerable